# How to install a digital certificate from the signed file programmatically?

Tags: c#, c++, import, installation, digital-certificate

If you have a digital signed file you can open the properties of the file and then install the certificate that the file was signed by clicking the Details -> Show certificate -> Install certificate. How to do this programmatically (e.g. in .net or unmanaged c++)?

Is it possible to read and install the certificate from the executable file itself?

Answer (score 0):

Certificates are included into the Authenticode signature of PE (and some other) files. If you have an Authenticode reader class, you can extract the certificates. Once you have them, you can install them to Windows Certificate storage.

Authenticode is supported by our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-pki.php) product, and so are certificate management and Windows Certificate storage operations.

With CryptoAPI this can be done using [WinVerifyTrust](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382384%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function followed by [CertAddCertificateContextToStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376009%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. But CryptoAPI is cumbersome.

Comment: I have found an example how to read the authenticode signature http://www.ucosoft.com/how-to-program-to-retrieve-the-authenticode-information.html.

Comment: Edit: but I can't put this all together, I need to read the authenticode signature in memory (not to save it on the file system) and add it to the certifucate store (local machine, trusted Publishers). Can you please provide a code sample?

Comment: @Shurup I am sorry but we have samples only for our components.